# How to put condition on update in stored procedure with two update statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with two updates statements like this:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE ASSYDAY 
    SET ASSYDAY.MAXORDERCAPACITY = AddCapacityToCalenders.max
    FROM ASSYDAY AS tableA
    JOIN LINEORDOCK AS tableB ON tableA.LINEORDOCKID = tableB.LINEORDOCKID
    JOIN AddCapacityToCalenders ON tableB.DESCRIPTION = AddCapacityToCalenders.Unit
    WHERE tableB.DESCRIPTION = (SELECT Unit FROM AddCapacityToCalenders) 
      AND tableA.ISWORKINGDAY = 0

    -- ================================================================================================
    -- Update workshopCalender

    UPDATE WORKSHOPCALENDAR
    SET MAXCAPACITY = AddCapacityToCalenders.max
    FROM WORKSHOPCALENDAR AS wrkShopCal
    JOIN WORKSHOP AS  wrkShop ON wrkShopCal.WORKSHOPGROUPID = wrkShop.WORKSHOPGROUPID
    JOIN WORKSHOPTRANSPORT wrkTra ON wrkShop.WORKSHOPID = wrkTra.WORKSHOPID
    JOIN FACTORY fct ON wrkTra.FACTORYID = fct.FACTORYID
    JOIN AddCapacityToCalenders ON fct.FACTORYCODE = AddCapacityToCalenders.FactoryCode
    WHERE fct.FACTORYCODE = (SELECT AddCapacityToCalenders.FactoryCode 
                             FROM AddCapacityToCalenders)
END
```

I need to read from a column in a third table and update based on the `workshopType`. Here is that table:

| workshopType | Maxcapacity |
| --- | --- |
| assy | Cell 2 |
| workshopCalender | Cell 4 |

This table is called `AddCapacityToCalenders`, I need to read from this if workshopType = 'assy' first update statement will be run, if its 'workshopCalender', the second one and in the future more workshops might be added, so it's going to be kind of a loop.

I hope I could make my point, thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @WorkshopType NVARCHAR(50)

    -- Read the workshopType from the AddCapacityToCalenders table
    SELECT @WorkshopType = workshopType 
    FROM AddCapacityToCalenders

    IF @WorkshopType = 'assy'
    BEGIN
        -- Update ASSYDAY table based on the workshopType
        UPDATE ASSYDAY 
        SET MAXORDERCAPACITY = AddCapacityToCalenders.MaxCapacity
        FROM ASSYDAY AS tableA
        JOIN LINEORDOCK AS tableB ON tableA.LINEORDOCKID = tableB.LINEORDOCKID
        JOIN AddCapacityToCalenders ON tableB.DESCRIPTION = AddCapacityToCalenders.Unit
        WHERE tableB.DESCRIPTION = @WorkshopType AND tableA.ISWORKINGDAY = 0
    END
    ELSE IF @WorkshopType = 'workshopCalender'
    BEGIN
        -- Update WORKSHOPCALENDAR table based on the workshopType
        UPDATE WORKSHOPCALENDAR
        SET MAXCAPACITY = AddCapacityToCalenders.MaxCapacity
        FROM WORKSHOPCALENDAR AS wrkShopCal
        JOIN WORKSHOP AS wrkShop ON wrkShopCal.WORKSHOPGROUPID = wrkShop.WORKSHOPGROUPID
        JOIN WORKSHOPTRANSPORT wrkTra ON wrkShop.WORKSHOPID = wrkTra.WORKSHOPID
        JOIN FACTORY fct ON wrkTra.FACTORYID = fct.FACTORYID
        JOIN AddCapacityToCalenders ON fct.FACTORYCODE = AddCapacityToCalenders.FactoryCode
        WHERE fct.FACTORYCODE = @WorkshopType
    END
    -- Add more ELSE IF conditions for other workshop types if needed

    -- If none of the workshopType conditions match, handle the case here
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Do something or raise an error if needed
    END

END
```

Comment: thats great but if i have multiple records what happenes?you select in the very first line can take only one record right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm baffled by the question, you already have a join to AddCapacityToCalenders to which you could add another clause eg

```
JOIN AddCapacityToCalenders ON tableB.DESCRIPTION = AddCapacityToCalenders.Unit
```

becomes

```
JOIN AddCapacityToCalenders ON tableB.DESCRIPTION = AddCapacityToCalenders.Unit and AddCapacityToCalenders = workshopType = 'ASSY'
```

this is then reundant - `tableB.DESCRIPTION = (SELECT Unit FROM AddCapacityToCalenders)`

Similar thing could be done with second update..

also in the 'future more workshops might be added' , what does that matter?
You are using tableB.DESCRIPTION = AddCapacityToCalenders.Unit in the first query and  fct.FACTORYCODE = AddCapacityToCalenders.FactoryCode in the second.. Did you mean more workshoptypes? if so then a loop isn't going to help.

Sample data and expected outcome as text would help as would the rest of the sp code